# Is it possible to compute argmax with or-tools with just one integer variable?

Tags: python, or-tools

Part of a models objective is weighted by items in a scalar list.

I am solving for this by using a list of 0-1 range variables, and then using LinearExpr.ScalProd to weight the objective.

Is there a way to do this with just one integer variable ( other than the objective variable), where I can either use a lambda or some other mechanism to lookup the value of a variable in a table?

Here is some sample code that I have that works, though I am trying to determine it can be made more concise.

```py
def argmax(
    model: cp_model.CpModel, values: List[int]
) -> Tuple[List[cp_model.IntVar], cp_model.IntVar]:
    objective_var = model.NewIntVar(0, 1000000, "objective_var")
    ret_vars = [model.NewIntVar(0, 1, "x(%i)" % i) for i in range(len(values))]
    model.Add(sum(ret_vars) == 1)
    model.Add(objective_var == cp_model.LinearExpr.ScalProd(ret_vars, values))

    return [ret_vars, objective_var]
```

Comment: This isn't really what you're looking for as an answer, but note that your `model.NewIntVar(0, 1, "x(%i)" % i)` could also simply be `model.NewBoolVar(f'x{i}')`.

Comment: Also, in your own initial solution, if you just want to pick up the index from `ret_vars`, you can get rid of `objective_var` entirely by using `model.Maximize(cp_model.LinearExpr.ScalProd(ret_vars, values))` directly.

Comment: Conversely, if you only need `objective_var`, a different (and much faster) approach would be to use the constraint `model.AddMaxEquality(objective_var, values)`. Out of curiosity, what's a use case where you would use or-tools to solve this problem rather than just use e.g. NumPy's `np.argmax` (which in practice is orders of magnitude faster)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I used IntVar since I thought that would be needed for the ScalProd.

Regarding argmax: I used argmax as an illustrative example to demonstrate what I was doing, I want to use it as part of maximizing a more complex objective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using model.AddElement.

```py
def AddElement(self, index, variables, target)
```

I found the documentation for AddElement to be a bit cryptic, so I'll try to curate it in what I'd think are simpler terms.

It states: `Adds the element constraint: variables[index] == target.`

- Index -> The variable you want to lookup with.
- Variables -> The table of lookup values.
- Target -> The value you want this to equal.

If anything, reading the C++ code makes it much simpler to understand.

```cpp
Constraint CpModelBuilder::AddElement(IntVar index,
                                      absl::Span<const int64> values,
                                      IntVar target) {
```

Putting this all together, we get:

```py
def argmax(
    model: cp_model.CpModel, values: List[int]
) -> Tuple[cp_model.IntVar, cp_model.IntVar]:
    objective_var = model.NewIntVar(0, 1000000, "objective_var")
    ret_var = model.NewIntVar(0, len(values) - 1, "x")
    model.AddElement(ret_var, values, objective_var)

    return [ret_var, objective_var]
```